# Sharing data between multiple java threads and get the updated value

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to create a java application , where we want to make rest calls for multiple users , with the help of an access token. I am using 1 thread per user . The access token, that I am using , is valid for 1 hour.Once the token expires , I will get an 401 error , and have to update the token for all the threads , and continue. I am thinking of using a volatile variable which I have made static to update all the threads. My requirement , is , the moment I get to know in one of threads that the token has expired , I want all the threads to stop processing and wait till the new token is generated(this takes couple of seconds).Also once generated , the token should be updated automatically , without each thread failing due to expired token.

Below is a sample code that I have written :

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Sample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] myStrings = { "User1" , "User2" , "User3" };

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors
            .newScheduledThreadPool(myStrings.length);

    TokenGenerator.getToken();

    for(String str : myStrings){
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(str), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
    }
}

}

 class Task implements Runnable{

private String name;

public Task(String name){
    this.name = name;

}


@Override
public void run() {

    getResponse(TokenGenerator.token);

}

private void getResponse(String token) {
    // Make http calls
    // if token expire , call getToken again. Pause all the running threads , and
    // update the token for all threads

    TokenGenerator.getToken();
}

 }

 class TokenGenerator {

public static volatile String token;

public static void getToken() {

    token = "new Token everytime";

}

 }
```

Is there a better approach to this problem? The above code does not satisfies my use case, since once a thread starts generating a new token, all other threads are not being paused. Request to suggest some improvements..

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong mate, you basically want all your threads to wait until one of them refreshes your token right?

Comment: yes..that is exactly what i want... in case one of the threads does get a fresh token, I want that value to be updated for all threads, irrespective of where the individual thread execution is, it should not try ever to use the old token and fail and create the token again...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put the token in an [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) and use a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) to pause the threads:

```
public class TokenWrapper {
  private final AtomicReference<Token> tokenRef = new AtomicReference<>(null);
  private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

  public TokenWrapper() {
    Token newToken = // refresh token
    tokenRef.set(newToken);
  }

  public Token getToken() {
    Token token = null;
    while((token = tokenRef.get()) == null) {
      semaphore.acquire();
    }
    return token;
  }

  public Token refreshToken(Token oldToken) {
    if(tokenRef.compareAndSet(oldToken, null)) {
      semaphore.drainPermits();          
      Token newToken = // refresh token
      tokenRef.set(newToken);
      semaphore.release(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
      return newToken;
    } else return getToken();
  }
}

public class RESTService {
  private static final TokenWrapper tokenWrapper = new TokenWrapper();

  public void run() {
    Token token = tokenWrapper.getToken();
    Response response = // call service with token
    if(response.getStatus == 401) {
      tokenWrapper.refreshToken(token);
    }
  }
}
```

`refreshToken()` uses an atomic `compareAndSet` on `tokenRef` to ensure that only one thread will refresh the token, and then calls `drainPermits()` on the `semaphore` to cause other threads to wait until the token is refreshed.  `getToken()` returns the token if it isn't `null`, else waits on the `semaphore` - this is done in a loop because it's possible that a thread will have to spin for a few cycles between `tokenRef` being set to `null` and `drainPermits()` being called on `semaphore`.

---

Edit: Modified the signature of `refreshToken(Token oldToken)` so that the old token is passed in rather than being read inside of the method - this is to prevent a situation where RESTService_A refreshes the token, RESTService_B gets a 401 with the old expired token, and then RESTService_B calls `refreshToken` after RESTService_A's call to `refreshToken` has completed, resulting in the token being refreshed twice.  With the new signature, RESTService_B will pass in the old expired token, and so the `compareAndSet` call will fail when the old token fails to match the new token, resulting in `refreshToken` only being called once.

Comment: This is exactly the type of solution I was looking for , something which I cant think of easily..thank you very much...

Comment: Thank you very much sir...You have completely solved my problem... This is perfect for me..:)

Comment: How other threads will be acknowledged if thread which is doing refreshToken throws error, how they should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following pattern, accessing the token only using its getter and calling `loadToken` when you receive the error response.

```
class TokenGenerator {
    private String token = null;
    public synchronized String getToken() {
        if (token == null) {
            loadToken();
        }
        return token;
    }
    public synchronized void loadToken() {
        token = "load here";
    }           
}
```

To address your problem of pausing threads, you can just call `getToken()` whereever you want halt the `Thread` which will automatically block in case loading the token is currently active.

```
class Task implements Runnable{
    private String name;
    private TokenGenerator tokenGenerator;

    public Task(String name, TokenGenerator tokenGenerator) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tokenGenerator = tokenGenerator;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        getResponse(tokenGenerator.getToken());
    }

    private void getResponse(String token) {
        // Make http calls
        // if token expire , call getToken again. Pause all the running threads , and
        // update the token for all threads

        tokenGenerator.loadToken();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..this makes the design much better...I will try to make some more improvements on this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to do two things(http calls and update token), you could try two way checker.

one to check if the token `is expired or not` and the other one is to check if any other thread is trying to `update the token`.

to demonstrate the idea here is a small code( its abit dirty way of doing it so it might need some cleaning up)

```
...
private string token
private volatile static isTokenExpired=false   //checking if the token is expired or not
private volatile static waitingForTokenRefresher=false;  //checking if we should wait for update.

@Override
public void run(){
  while(tokenisExpired){
      //wait
  }

  //http calls find out if token is good to go
  //check if no one else uses the token:
  if( token is actually expired){
   if(!waitingForTokenRefresher){
       isTokenExpired=true;
       waitingForTokenRefresher=true;
       //refresh token
       waitingForTokenRefresher=false
       isTokenExpired=false;
   }
  }
   while(!waitingForTokenRefresher){
     //wait...
   }

}
```