# How to keep common data required for multiple thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have a multi threaded environment. Within those threads I need to make some http call. This is an existing code.
Now the new requirement is that I need to pass a token to those call. So I need to keep this token to some where and need to get it during the call.

So my question is what will be the best implementation to keep the token.

I can store the token in some singleton class and get the value from there. What will be the merit / demerit of this approach.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: this token is static or dynamic?

Comment: How about making use of Future / CompletableFuture API of Java for you to keep the relationship of the token and the result of those asynchronous calls to make it easier to handle?

Comment: @Devratna, the token will have its own life-cycle. But during the http call, what ever token is available, will be passed.

Comment: I would just create some kind of ApiToken class that contains the data required to make the call. Then you can just pass the object to whatever method call and  you can integrate it into the http request.

Comment: @martijnp, from were the object of that class will be instantiated? If I need to create the object in every thread, I need to get the token every time.

Comment: It really depends on the context of the application. If the sole purpose is making an a http call then you could put it in some kind of client wrapper from where you can make requests and attach an api token present in the same class. If you have a full on application I suggest you use something like a configuration file, environment file or something alike to store and fetch the api token from. This way it would be safer too, since other people who use the application will need their own api tokens.

Comment: Thanx @martijnp, but I can't put the token into any file. I need to keep it in memory only. And the token has its own life-cycle, ie, its value can be changed by some other thread. So my query was "how to store / keep the token in memory in efficient manner?" I can write a singleton class to keep the token. I can easily get the token from that singleton class. Now is there any better way to keep the token?

Comment: Hey @Amit take a look at this [shared token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893299/sharing-data-between-multiple-java-threads-and-get-the-updated-value) It may provide you some direction.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you store it, you need to store it in thread safe memory.  For example, you could declare the variable used to store it `volatile`.

For ease of access, you could use a singleton, but a static variable in a convenient class might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to generate some token from parent thread then you can use in child threads in during Http request.

The below approach can be used. You can use the InheritableThreadLocal variable to store the token and then it can be used safely by the child threads.

```
public class ThreadContext {
    private static ThreadLocal<String> currentThread = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

    public static String getCurrentThread() {
        return currentThread.get();
    }

    public static void setCurrentThread(String tenant) {
        currentThread.set(tenant);
    }

    public static void clear() {
        currentThread.set(null);
    }
}
```

You can set the token using the ThreadContext.setCurrentThread(String tenant) method. And in the child thread, you can use ThreadContext.getCurrentThread();