# Storing an JWT for a Spring API client service

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety

I have a Service that is calling a remote API to fetch data.
It is authorized with a service account, and I store the JWT-Token for my requests inside the service as a class variable.

When one of the methods gets a 401 response, the service tries to authenticate and stores the new JWT inside the old variable.
I could make the Service a Bean with a request scope, but I would like to avoid that.

Can somebody help me to make the JWT class variable thread-safe?
e.g. what happens if 2 requests try to update the JWT token at the same time?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893299/sharing-data-between-multiple-java-threads-and-get-the-updated-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the JWT token is the same for all requests then you could use `AtomicReference`. Before making a remote call use the `getToken()`
and apply the value to the request headers.

For example:

```
/**
 * Initialize it with an expired {@link OAuthToken} so we don't ever need to make a '{@code null}' check.
 */
private final AtomicReference<OAuthToken> atomicRefToken = new AtomicReference<>(OAuthToken.expiredToken());


public OAuthToken getToken() {
    if (atomicRefToken.get().isExpired()) {
        atomicRefToken.set(this.fetchToken());
    }
    return atomicRefToken.get();
}

private OAuthToken fetchToken() {
    // fetch token via some call
    return new OAuthToken(....)
}
```

Example of the `OAuthToken` class.

```
public class OAuthToken implements Serializable {

    public static final String TOKEN_TYPE_BEARER = "bearer";


    public static final Long SPARE_SECONDS = 100L;


    private final String tokenType;
    private final String accessToken;
    private final Long expiresIn;
    private final LocalDateTime expiresAt;

    public OAuthToken(@JsonProperty("token_type") @NonNull String tokenType,
                      @JsonProperty("access_token") @NonNull String accessToken,
                      @JsonProperty("expires_in") @NonNull Long expiresIn) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
        this.expiresAt = LocalDateTime.now().plus(expiresIn - SPARE_SECONDS, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance where the token is expired.
     *
     * @return new instance
     */
    public static OAuthToken expiredToken() {
        return new OAuthToken(TOKEN_TYPE_BEARER, "expired", 0L);
    }

    public boolean isExpired() {
        return LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(expiresAt);
    }

    public String value() {
        return this.accessToken;
    }

}
```